# Counter code for paginated category pages in wordpress

Tags: query-posts, query

I am trying to customize the category template whereby I wish to show the ordered list of 10 posts on each page. I am using the following code in the loop:

```
<?php $counter = 1; 
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="entry">
        <?php echo $counter++; the_excerpt(''); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

On the first page: it shows the excerpts arranged in a 1 to 10 ordered list, but on the second page (using wp-pagenavi), it again starts from 1. Is there any way that all the posts of a category can be shown in a consistent ordered list from post 1 to last post.

Comment: Don't trust this 100% percent, but I'm pretty sure you can get_query_var('posts_per_page') *   (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 + your counter.
In essence, which page am I at? **times** how many posts do I display on each page? **plus** this is the how-many'eth post on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it starts again at 1. You've initialized the counter to 1 on each page load.

If you were writing a custom loop you'd do this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

If normal WordPress pagination mechanisms are working on your page that should work for you too. That will number your pages. Your counter should start at `$paged` times your posts per page, minus your posts per page. So with ten posts per page...

1. Page 1 -> `$paged = 1` -> 1 * 10 = 10 -> 10 minus 10 = 0 -> Start at zero
2. Page 2 -> `$paged = 2` -> 2 * 10 = 20 -> 20 minus 10 = 10 -> Start at 10

Of course humans start counting at 1 but if you increment the counter before you print it, problem solved.

```
<?php 
$mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp; 
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    $counter++; // that pushes the zero based counter up one ?> 
    <div class="entry">
        <?php echo $counter; the_excerpt(''); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Untested. Maybe buggy. But I am pretty sure it is on the right track.