# How to add sort order to incremented and paginated category loop

Tags: wp-query, loop

I used this in a loop on a category template to get a numbered lists of posts that continues in the next page:

```
<?php 
   $mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
   $counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp; 
   while(have_posts()) : the_post(); $counter++; ?>

     <div class="entry">
         <?php echo $counter; the_title(''); ?>
     </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It was suggested by [s-ha-dum](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) as an [answer to another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80048/160457) on StackExchange.

However, I need this loop to sort posts in asc order, and I am not sure how to do that with all these variables in place. Normally, I would use something like the following before the loop and it would work perfectly:

```
<?php $sortorder= new WP_Query( 'orderby=date&sort=asc' ); ?>
```

The end result of the code is this:

```
<?php 
   $mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
   $counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp;
   $sortorder= new WP_Query( 'orderby=date&sort=asc' );
   while ( $sortorder->have_posts() ) : $sortorder->the_post(); $counter++ ?>

     <div class="entry">
         <?php echo $counter; the_title(''); ?>
     </div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But this is not working as expected. It does sort them in ascending order, but all pages show the same list of titles, with only the number changing. So the same 10 titles are shown in page one, numbered 1-10, then again in page 2, but numbered from 11... and so on.

So please excuse my ignorance and help me understand where I am going wrong and how to fix it.

Thank you.

---

**Update: This is the final working query:**

```
<?php
   $mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
   $counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp; 
   $query = new WP_Query( array(
       'category_name' => 'research',
       'paged' => $paged, 
       'posts_per_page' => 20, 
       'orderby' => 'date',
       'order' => 'asc',
   ) );

   while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); $counter++ ?>

      <div class="entry">
          <?php echo $counter; the_title(''); ?>
      </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

---

**Update #2: Improved answer based on further comments by [Jaydip Nimavat](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/123295/jaydip-nimavat).**

The loop in the category page template is now:

```
<?php
   $mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
   $counter = ($mypage * $ppp) - $ppp;

   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $counter++ ?>

      <div class="entry">
          <?php echo $counter; the_title(''); ?>
      </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And the `functions.php` now includes:

```
// Sort order for research, articles, and literature category pages
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category( array('research','articles','literature') )) {
      $qobj = get_queried_object();
      if( isset($qobj->taxonomy) && 'category' == $qobj->taxonomy ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
      }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

And everything works perfectly. Thank you, Jaydip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pagination parameters to `WP_Query`,
[Check Here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

---

Please check your query:
`$sortorder= new WP_Query( 'orderby=date&sort=asc' );`

There is no parameter of `posts_per_page` and `paged`, so it will get the same ( 1st ) page result only each time and display the same data.

---

If you want to manage just some parameters only in the main query, do not use custom query use `pre_get_posts` hook.

Please check:

```
<?php
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category()) {
      $qobj = get_queried_object();
      if( isset($qobj->taxonomy) && 'category' == $qobj->taxonomy ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
      }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: Can you clarify your answer, please? Because I'm not sure how that works with $counter as well.

Comment: Check I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I thought the query was taking my default `posts_per_page number` from the WordPress settings, so I didn't think to add it. But it is working now, and I have updated my original question to include the final query. However, I also had to add the `category_name` to the array, despite this being a `category` template. While the previous version of my query listed the correct category posts without that addition, the final working query gave mixed results and the addition of `category_name` became a necessity. Do you know if this is expected or am I missing something?

Comment: By "gave mixed results" do you mean it gives a result from all the posts ( including custom post type? ) then you need to add `post_type` parameter. by default, it uses all. please check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: I am not using custom posts types, just the core posts and pages. I have about 200+ posts, and the research category only has 48. Without the `category_name` parameter, the query displayed 60 post titles in 3 pages, and took posts from nearly every category that I have.

Comment: I just want some category pages (for which I have made specific templates in my theme, like `category-research.php`) to list posts in **ascending** order, while maintaining **pagination with auto-numbering** (using the $counter). Would best practice be achieved with `WP_Query` or `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: Please check added code for `pre_get_posts`. In `$qobj` you have term all details. like `term_id, slug, name` etc. you can manage that to the if condition.